# I want get month() function return value as 'jan',feb etc

Tags: php, mysql

I want output of Mysql Month() function as 'Jan',Feb etc.

Comment: Voting to close as to broad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(curdate());
```

### [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)

or if you only need the first 3 letters

```
SELECT substr(MONTHNAME(curdate()), 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use  date_format

```
select DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15", "%b");
```